# How can I specify different dimension of layout for different density

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I specify  dimension of layout for different density of screen?
i.e. the layout are the same across different densities, but some dimension are different.
how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

```
//1.create different dimens.xml in different resource folders as below 

 res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml
 res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
 res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml

 //Then Android will decide which file to use. 

//2.Create  dimensions values in respective dimens.xml file according to the need as below


 <!-- in values-ldpi/dimens.xml -->
 <dimen name="textSize">25dip</dimen>

// and..

 <!-- in values-mdpi/dimens.xml -->
 <dimen name="textSize">20dip</dimen>

// etc. 
// 3.Don't care about resolution Android will take care of which resource to fetch.
// 4.Mention size in  dp instead of pixels.
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for solution that you shared with us! You saved my day man. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 2):

you define you layout and put it under

res/layout-Qualifier/my_layout.xml
where Qualifier could be one or more of the following

size : small, normal, large

density: ldpi,mdpi, hdpi.

For example layout for large screen with high density would be
res/layout-hdpi-large/my_layout.xml

For full list of attributes see answer above

Comment: But that mean I need to copy and past my 'my_layout.xml' file to different directories with only the width/height values different?  Can I put 3 different dimens.xml files and have my_layout.xml to look it up?

Comment: Yes, Copy the same my_layout.xml in all directories & cchnage the alignment or the sizes according to the size of the screen or the dpi

Answer (score 0):

You can use different units to have the dimensions adapt to the screen.

> Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp
>   (scaled pixels based on preferred font
>   size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

[Available Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)