# Cannot display image from json with the required dimensions in ImageView of android

Tags: android, json, image

I want to display an image in android's ImageView in this format.
[image]

I am trying to read my image from json(by an url) which i have hosted on a server.The image from the json looks like this :- [image]

**But when i try to read the url from my server(by json) my layout looks like this** [image]

If i try to load the image locally from device i get the reqired format(1st image of this question), but if i try to load the image via json's url i get a shrunked image.

Here is my json:-

```
{"events": [{
            "Name": "Chicken Manchuri",
            "Time": "30 mins",
            "Serves": "4",
            "ingredients": "http://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2015/06/19/salogo2ec23.png",
            "prize2": "Worth Rs.2000",
            "Description": "How do you decide whether or not to try a new recipe? Ohh yes, there are different ways to make your decision. You can decide based on your experience, say you tried something new at a restaurant or at a friend’s place, you liked it, so you want to try it. You heard one of your friends raving about a new recipe she tried and she strongly recommends you to try it. You visit blogs like this, see the pics, read the comments and make the decision. Sometimes  you read about something, but you’ve no idea what it is, you havent heard anybody recommending it, but you’ve a good feeling about it, so you give it a try. Phew, I’m exhausted explaining the decision making process!How do you decide whether or not to try a new recipe? Ohh yes, there are different ways to make your decision. You can decide based on your experience, say you tried something new at a restaurant or at a friend’s place, you liked it, so you want to try it. You heard one of your friends raving about a new recipe she tried and she strongly recommends you to try it. You visit blogs like this, see the pics, read the comments and make the decision. Sometimes  you read about something, but you’ve no idea what it is, you havent heard anybody recommending it, but you’ve a good feeling about it, so you give it a try. Phew, I’m exhausted explaining the decision making process!How do you decide whether or not to try a new recipe? Ohh yes, there are different ways to make your decision. You can decide based on your experience, say you tried something new at a restaurant or at a friend’s place, you liked it, so you want to try it. You heard one of your friends raving about a new recipe she tried and she strongly recommends you to try it. You visit blogs like this, see the pics, read the comments and make the decision. Sometimes  you read about something, but you’ve no idea what it is, you havent heard anybody recommending it, but you’ve a good feeling about it, so you give it a try. Phew, I’m exhausted explaining the decision making process!",
            "date": "Coming soon"
        },

            "Name": "Chicken Manchuri",
            "Time": "30 mins",
            "Serves": "4",
            "ingredients": "http://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2015/06/19/salogo2ec23.png",
            "prize2": "Worth Rs.2000",
            "Description": "How do you decide whether or not to try a new recipe? Ohh yes, there are different ways to make your decision. You can decide based on your experience, say you tried something new at a restaurant or at a friend’s place, you liked it, so you want to try it. You heard one of your friends raving about a new recipe she tried and she strongly recommends you to try it. You visit blogs like this, see the pics, read the comments and make the decision. Sometimes  you read about something, but you’ve no idea what it is, you havent heard anybody recommending it, but you’ve a good feeling about it, so you give it a try. Phew, I’m exhausted explaining the decision making process!",
            "date": "Coming soon"
        },
    {
            "Name": "Chicken Manchuri",
            "Time": "30 mins",
            "Serves": "4",
            "ingredients": "http://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2015/06/19/salogo2ec23.png",
            "prize2": "Worth Rs.2000",
            "Description": "How do you decide whether or not to try a new recipe? Ohh yes, there are different ways to make your decision. You can decide based on your experience, say you tried something new at a restaurant or at a friend’s place, you liked it, so you want to try it. You heard one of your friends raving about a new recipe she tried and she strongly recommends you to try it. You visit blogs like this, see the pics, read the comments and make the decision. Sometimes  you read about something, but you’ve no idea what it is, you havent heard anybody recommending it, but you’ve a good feeling about it, so you give it a try. Phew, I’m exhausted explaining the decision making process!",
            "date": "Coming soon"
        }
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#81345a"

    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_maxresdefault" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="Styling Android"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
            android:textColor="#CCC"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Json.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

     static final String NAME = "Name";
     static final String TIME = "Time";
     static final String VENUE = "Serves";
     static final String ingredients = "ingredients";
     static final String PRIZE_MONEY2 = "prize2";
     static final String REGISTRATION_FEE = "date";
     static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();


    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();

           /* TitanicTextView tv=(TitanicTextView)findViewById(R.id.titanic_tv);
            Titanic tt=new Titanic();
            tt.start(tv);*/
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://lit-hamlet-6856.herokuapp.com/eventsList/TECHNICAL");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("events");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("Name", jsonobject.getString("Name"));
                    map.put("Time", jsonobject.getString("Time"));
                    map.put("Serves", jsonobject.getString("Serves"));
                    map.put("ingredients", jsonobject.getString("ingredients"));
                    map.put("Description",jsonobject.getString("Description"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            //setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Imageloader.java

```
package com.example.hasan.jsoncountries;

/**
 * Created by hasan on 13/6/15.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

I want the final output to be like this.

[image]
So what should i do to get it right ?

Comment: json looks like this? you missed to copy it, right ?

Comment: @Karoly sorry i did not get you

Comment: Post some code, please

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I thought you are going to share the JSON code as well. What is the problem ? If I understand you well, you are able to display the image in a listview, but it is smaller than you expected ?

Comment: @Karoly exactly correct, if i try to load image via json it is small, but if i ry to load locally it is fine

Comment: Paste the code where u download and parse the stream.

Comment: @EE66 i have added the code, but i dont think it will actually matter

Comment: how do you parse the JSON man ? The image is getting smaller because you are displaying into a list, which have to fit in the screen as well.

Comment: the part that u load the image into the imageview.

Comment: @Karoly kindly see my edited question, i have put an image as the required output(it is in listview)

Comment: Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(previewImage);  Just try this. pass context, url and imageview.  dependencies     compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'

Comment: @penta, I have added an answer please check it.

Comment: i am trying it please wiat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scalType FIT_XY and a large imageview (heigh: X, width:wrap_content) will do the job, but not the best solution. X is in dp and you can add different values to it by res/values/dimens.xml.

about multiple dimens:
[How can I specify different dimension of layout for different density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836352/how-can-i-specify-different-dimension-of-layout-for-different-density)

If you have to use different DP values which may change based on the density category of the device, than you should need to create different dimens files based on small,large,xlarge
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Okay, Ill try my best: First I would like to recommend this library for ImageDownloading from URL:
http://square.github.io/picasso/
It`s a well writen library, I always use it when I can.

Comment: i tried your above solution by changing the xml code, i get the same output(small images)

Comment: what if the android shrink them, because they have to fit in the list? Try to give exact height to iw: like 90dp @penta

Comment: then it should have shrunk them even when loading the images locally

Comment: i changed the height n width of the image view, i got my required result, but this cannot be correct solution as height and width will change form device to device and so will the image view

Comment: you can solve this problem with an android way:
@dimen/ use dimension! res/value/dimens.xml

Comment: can you please be more brief about ur above comment :-) , how can setting the dimen help me in getting into my goal

Comment: If you have to use different DP values which may change based on the density category of the device, than you should need to create different dimens files based on small,large,xlarge.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80983/discussion-between-karoly-and-penta).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: i get it like this http://postimg.org/image/jzbjds0lp/ i want the image to take its original size

Comment: Ah okay. Could you please provide the code snippet there you loade the Image to your ImageView?

Comment: see my edited question, i have put the java file and my required output.